# Instiantiating different subclasses based on arguments

Tags: python, python-2.7, oop

I have a `RoundRobinChecker` and a `PlayoffChecker` class, both inheriting from `ViolationChecker`, which checks whether a given round-robin or playoff match passes the rules or not.

The constructor has one argument, the match: `ViolationChecker(match)`. Now, if the match is a playoff match (`match.playoff`), a `PlayoffChecker` should be instantiated, otherwise it should be a `RoundRobinChecker`. I could just do this:

```
checkers = [PlayoffChecker(match) if match.playoff else RoundRobinChecker(match) for match in matches]
```

But this is kind of an unclean way of doing it. Would it be possible to just call the parent class constructor, `ViolationChecker(match)`, and this would create the instance of the corresponding subclass?

What design could I use here to choose the appropriate class in a transparent way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to make `ViolationChecker(match)` work, you can override the [`__new__` method](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__) in your parent class like this:

```
class ViolationChecker:
    def __new__(cls, match):
        if match.playoff:
            cls= PlayoffChecker
        else:
            cls= RoundRobinChecker

        inst= object.__new__(cls)
        return inst #implicit call to inst.__init__(match)
```

However, it's not obvious to someone who reads your code that `ViolationChecker(match)` returns an instance of a subclass. I recommend adding a staticmethod with a clear name to `ViolationChecker`, something like this:

```
class ViolationChecker:
    @staticmethod
    def new_for_match(match):
        if match.playoff:
            cls= PlayoffChecker
        else:
            cls= RoundRobinChecker

        inst= cls(match)
        return inst
```

Now you can do `ViolationChecker.new_for_match(match)`, which conveys the intention of creating a `ViolationChecker` specifically for this `match` instance more clearly.